# Open source license that only affects code

Tags: license-recommendation, mit, source-code, exceptions, media

I have a repository (a website) available on Github which contains code, media and texts.

Everything is freely available (either on the website or via the code on Github). I want to let the code available under an open source license (MIT, for example), but I don't want the license to apply on media and texts. These are my company's properties and cannot be redistributed or modified.

- Is there a way to change the license to explicitly say that?
- Can I use a license for the code and another (or nothing) for the rest?
- Does a license already offer that?

I know that I can remove the license and just state that the project is unlicensed (even if visible on Github), but I would rather open source the code.

Comment: Just say at the top of your license file that it only applies to the code.

Comment: @curiousdannii, better add a file stating exactly what files are covered by what license.

Comment: Can you simply not put the media and text in the same repository, perhaps making that repository private? Your code may have to be updated to gracefully handle media not being present or alternate media files being present, but it would probably be the easiest solution.

Comment: I don't want to split the repo in two. Too complex for something so small. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to add a file stating exactly what files are available under which conditions if you provide all. You'll have to ask the company lawyer for exact details.

You might want to replace the non-distributable/non-changeable files with some sort of replacement or at least a mockup.

It makes little sense to share the software unless there is a way to replace those pieces by a would-be-user. Please give some description of restrictions they have to fulfil (format, contents, size, whatever).